# Java : Taking 2 array find if the element that exists in both array return true if exist else false

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am looking for some  clarification on this solution. Can anyone guide me on the following two points:

1. Is the below algorithm good solution?
2. and is my Big O calculation correct?

your clarification is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    String[] b = {"z", "f", "c"};

    boolean value1 = find(a, b);
    System.out.println(value1);

    boolean value2 = findArray(a, b);
    System.out.println(value2);

}

/*
since the both the array is of diff size for nested loop
Big O  = O(n*n)
if array size is same Big O = O(n^2)
 */
private static boolean find(String[] a, String[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        String val1 = a[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (val1.equals(b[j])) {
                System.out.println(val1 + " : " + b[j]);

                return true;
            }
        }// O(n)
    }// O(n)
    return false;
}// O(n*n)

/*
Big O  = O(n)
 */
private static boolean findArray(String[] a, String[] b) {
    //create array list from array
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b));
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        String val1 = a[i]; //O(1)

        if (list.contains(val1)) {
            System.out.println(val1 + " : contain in list b");
            return true;
        }// O(1)

    }// O(n)
    return false;
}// O(n)
```

Comment: Isn't  this question more a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think that both algorithms looks reasonable.
2. ArrayList.contains time complexity is O(n).

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. **All of the other operations run in linear time** (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there any better way to solve this problem in terms on time complexity .

Comment: Glad to help! I cant think of any better solution than what @mondayguy has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is also O(N^2), because contain works O(N) under the hood.

**First Solution O(N*LogN):**

1. Sort second array. NLogN
2. Iterate throught first one O(N) and [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) via second
   one O(logN) => O(NLogN)

Overall complexity O(NLogN)

**Second solution O(N) - if arrays are sorted. If not O(NLogN), because of step 1**

1. Sort both of arrays O(NlogN)
2. Do something like this

Code:

```
int curA = 0, curB = 0;
while (true) {
 if (curA >= a.length || curB >= b.length)
  break;
 if (a[curA] < b[curB]) {
  curA++;
  continue;
 }

 if (a[curA] > b[curB]) {
  curB++;
  continue;
 }

 return true;
}
return false;
```